# How to get rid of the space between greek and non-greek letters in ToExpression

Tags: formatting, latex

First I tried the following:

```
ToExpression["$\\delta\\alpha$", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

and then as expected, I got

```
\[Delta]\[Alpha]
```

Then I tried

```
ToExpression["$\\delta a$", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

and I got

```
\[Delta] a
```

with an unexpected space between a $\delta$ and $a$. A standard LaTeX interpreter will not add a space between $\delta$ and $a$.

**My question is**: how can I get rid of the space between the greek letter delta and the latin letter a?

I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A standard LaTeX interpreter will not add a space between $\delta$ and $a$.

This is not a "space".  It is multiplication.

LaTeX does not understand the meaning of formulae and has no concept of multiplication.  LaTeX only does typesetting.  LaTeX code is not appropriate for representing precise mathematical meaning.

`ToExpression` needs to convert it to a meaningful mathematical expression.  It has to decide whether you meant one symbol named $\delta\alpha$ or the multiplication of two distinct symbols, $\delta\times\alpha$.  `ToExpression` does not preserve typesetting.  It makes a guess about the mathematical meaning and gives you the corresponding expression, which can be typeset in multiple different ways.

The guesses is makes are not always good.  I believe the idea is that you will correct them manually.  So I suggest just fixing the output by hand.

---

If you really need to get this output automatically, a possible solution is to convert the LaTeX to MathML using some other, more configurable tool.  Then import the MathML to Mathematica.  I would try this if I had to process hundreds of such inputs.